# Prevent ansible from using sudo

Tags: python, ansible, sudo

I am trying to run an ansible playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i myserver.com, ansible/playbooks/myplaybook.yml -vvv
```

But it tries to execute sudo commands on a remote server where **I don't have sudo rights** and just hangs when prompted for the password:

```
<myserver.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: my_username on PORT 22 TO myserver.com
<myserver.com> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<myserver.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460997867.84-241373750954463 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460997867.84-241373750954463 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460997867.84-241373750954463'
<myserver.com> PUT /var/folders/31/y5npmcgn7777f5063rgjf6_hc7rppt/T/tmptR7HbV TO /home/my_username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-14609823867.84-241373750954463/setup
<myserver.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=afasdfakjdfasdgrefavf] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-mwpxbbscfnbmmgqspgerjcwapghlvcbo; LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /home/my_username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-14609823867.84-241373350954463/setup; rm -rf /home/my_username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-14609823867.84-241373350954463/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''

failed: [myserver.com] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
[sudo via ansible, key=afasdfakjdfasdgrefavf] password:
```

The playbook seems to work for other people on my team so I am not sure what's happening and this is my first experience with Ansible so I apolgoze if I'm missing something obvious.

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars_prompt:
  - name: "my_brancyh"
    prompt: "My branch:"
    default: "dev"
    private: no
  - name: "password"
    prompt: "Enter password"

  vars:
    proxy_url: "my_proxy"

  environment:
    PASSWORD: "{{password}}"
    HTTP_PROXY: http://{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}:{{password}}@{{proxy_url}}:8099
    HTTPS_PROXY: http://{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}:{{password}}@{{proxy_url}}:8099

  tasks:
  - name: create my environment
    shell: "{{item}}"
    with_items:
      - /opt/anaconda/anaconda/bin/conda create -y -p ~/envs/alvin --no-default-packages --no-pin python==2.7.9
      - mkdir ~/envs/my/src
```

Comment: Please add the first lines of ansible/playbooks/myplaybook.yml to know how help to you.

Comment: Sorry, had to cleanse some of the proprietary stuff out of there, let me know if this is missing something it needs.

Comment: I just read an article about some guy runing `rm -rf /`  on his ansible network that he hosted 1500 websites on (and the backups were also on the network) ... boy that guy could have benefitted from not running as sudo

Comment: @JoranBeasley [It was a falsified story](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8696/12214).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /etc/ansible/ansible.conf or ~/.ansible.cfg maybe your environment is setting sudo as global parameter.

Comment: This sounds like it's on the right track but when I run `ansible-playbook -i myserver.com, -u myuser ansible/playbooks/myplaybook.yml -vvv` it still tries to run sudo commands and hits the same issue.  User seems to be fine on local but on the remote machine it looks like it is still trying to use root.

Comment: Check your /etc/ansible/ansible.conf  maybe your environment is setting sudo as global parameter.

Comment: That was it.  I used a package at another point in time that modified my `~/.ansible.cfg` and it was setting user to root.  If you make that into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible only attempts to use `sudo` when you specify in the playbook that you want it (via the `sudo` or `become` directives), or when specified on the command-line (`--sudo` or `--become`).  I don't see either of those things in your example, but you say this is a reduced playbook - did you remove one of those from a task when removing internal information?

Comment: I didn't remove any sudo commands and I don't see anything in the playbook but I'm going to try to run it a few lines at a time to see if something in there is causing it.  The fact that I'm the only one having the issue makes me wonder if it has something to do with my environment so I'm checking that now too.